# How i can optimize the multiple 'for' loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am using a code snippet similar to code below to generate a billions of data. But it is taking very long time to generate the data.

Sorry to not mention it earlier,
i am also using python faker for generating some data and I am using this script to generate data and load it into RDS

Thank you very much for all the response.

***A similar code that I am working on has been updated ***

```
  class Provider(BaseProvider):
        def custom_id(self):
            date_part = faker.date_of_birth(minimum_age=18, maximum_age=65).strftime('%Y%m%d')
            two_digit_number = str(random.randint(10, 99))
            segment1 = str(random.randint(10**8, 10**9 - 1))
            segment2 = str(random.randint(10**9, 10**10 - 1))
            custom_id = f"{date_part}-{two_digit_number}--{segment1}-{segment2}"
            return custom_id
 for day in range(days_to_loop):
        start_time = start_date + timedelta(days=day)    
        for x in x_list:
            for interval in range(48): 
                for y in y_list:
                    for z in z_list:
                        interval_number = (interval % 48) + 1
                        intervaltimestamp = start_time + timedelta(minutes=30 * interval)
                        intervalendtimestamp = intervaltimestamp + timedelta(minutes=30)                        
                        _id = faker.custom_id()
                        x = x
                        dateid = intervaltimestamp.strftime('%Y%m%d')
                        intervalnumber = interval
                        value = faker.random.randint(1, 1000)
                        queue = z
                        instance = z+ y
                        y = y                      
                        rows_buffer.append({'id': _id, 'x': x, 
                            'instance': instance,'dateid': dateid, 'intervalnumber': intervalnumber,
                            'value': value, 'intervaltimestamp': intervaltimestamp, 'intervalendtimestamp': intervalendtimestamp,
                            'y': y,'queue': queue})                        
    with open('test1.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        fieldnames = ['id','x', 'instance', 'dateid', 'intervalnumber','value','intervaltimestamp','intervalendtimestamp','y','queue']

        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(rows_buffer)
```

Comment: How fast do you expect writing billions of lines of csv to be? Writing to disk is slow relative to the execution of the code you have shown.

Comment: Rewrite it in C?

Comment: It looks like this is going to be completely I/O bound, unless there's something expensive going on in the code that writes the values (which you didn't show).  If it is in fact I/O bound, then there probably isn't anything you can do in your code to speed it up.

Comment: You could test a write to disk to see how long that takes. On linux, you could use `dd` to write the same sized file. Is the python version slower? You could also see how much CPU the python program is using. If I/O bound, it will be < 100%. If you have a lot of memory - enough to hold the data in cache - then it'll be a future sync to disk that is slow. If you have an SSD, it'll be faster than spinning media. Once again, linux, but you could do a `sync` before running the program to start getting data out of the cache right away.

Comment: If you're writing to csv, you're writing text. Assuming UTF8 and a line length of about 255 standard characters, you're writing a quarter of a terabyte per billion rows. As mentioned above, the python loop isn't going to be the bottleneck there. Is csv the right option there? Parquet or similar may be significantly smaller file size and so significantly faster to write...

Answer (score -2):

1. Put the longest loop in the innermost layer and the shortest loop in the outermost layer.
2. Optimize your data structure. If your data is all number, try to use numpy library.

Comment: You have to go through all of them anyway. The order of the for loop won't make a difference on speed. It will just be a reordering of the final data. Depending on what is being calculated, it may not work at all.

Comment: It not the comparison between the total number of the data. The time complexity will be the same. When the outer loop iterates over the longer list, the inner loop, which is more costly in terms of entering and exiting, has more iterations, resulting in slower overall execution. You can compare between them. Thanks

Comment: The code suite in the inner loop is where all of the cost is. It runs just as many times, regardless of which order the for's are written. Maybe you could save a couple of entries into the inner for, but that is trivial. Its nothing compared to everything in the inner suite.